# Ubuntu Server GUI login issue

Tags: 12.04

I have installed Ubuntu server 12.04, and have a command line interface the works great. However, when I start lightdm I can only log into the GUI as guest, not as the user that I created.Is there something that I am missing here? It worked one day, now it no longer works. The screen flashes black for a second, then takes me right back to the login screen where I have the option to login as the user or as a guest user. Additionally, each time I do that it has been creating zombie processes that I am having to go in and kill each time. I have included the .xsession-errors from root below.

Xsession: X session started for root at Thu Mar 13 10:39:10 EDT 2014
localuser:root being added to access control list
Setting IM through im-switch for locale=en_US.
Start IM through /etc/X11/xinit/xinput.d/all_ALL linked to /etc/X11/xinit/xinput.d/default.
GNOME_KEYRING_CONTROL=/tmp/keyring-iiFHtd
SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/tmp/keyring-iiFHtd/ssh
GNOME_KEYRING_PID=2420
GNOME_KEYRING_CONTROL=/tmp/keyring-iiFHtd
SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/tmp/keyring-iiFHtd/ssh
GPG_AGENT_INFO=/tmp/keyring-iiFHtd/gpg:0:1
GNOME_KEYRING_CONTROL=/tmp/keyring-iiFHtd
SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/tmp/keyring-iiFHtd/ssh
GPG_AGENT_INFO=/tmp/keyring-iiFHtd/gpg:0:1
GNOME_KEYRING_CONTROL=/tmp/keyring-iiFHtd
SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/tmp/keyring-iiFHtd/ssh
GPG_AGENT_INFO=/tmp/keyring-iiFHtd/gpg:0:1

** (gnome-settings-daemon:2418): WARNING **: Failed to connect context: OK
Checking if settings need to be migrated ...no
Checking if internal files need to be migrated ...no
Backend     : gconf
Integration : true
Profile     : default
Adding plugins
Initializing core options...done
Initializing composite options...done
** Message: applet now removed from the notification area
** Message: using fallback from indicator to GtkStatusIcon
Initializing opengl options...done
Initializing decor options...done
Initializing vpswitch options...done
Initializing snap options...done
Initializing mousepoll options...done
Initializing resize options...done
Initializing place options...done
Initializing move options...done
Initializing wall options...done
Initializing grid options...done
I/O warning : failed to load external entity "/root/.compiz/session/102153c4caa7fad67139472155474283100000024050034"
Initializing session options...done
Initializing gnomecompat options...done
Initializing animation options...done
Initializing fade options...Initializing nautilus-gdu extension
done
Initializing workarounds options...done
Initializing scale options...done
compiz (expo) - Warn: failed to bind image to texture
Initializing expo options...done
Initializing ezoom options...done
Initializing staticswitcher options...done
Initializing unitymtgrabhandles options...done
Initializing unityshell options...done
Setting Update "run_command_terminal_key"
Setting Update "fullscreen_visual_bell"
Setting Update "autoraise"
Setting Update "autoraise_delay"
Setting Update "toggle_window_shaded_key"
Setting Update "fullscreen_visual_bell"
Setting Update "run_command_terminal_key"
Starting gtk-window-decorator
Connection failure: Connection refused
pa_context_connect() failed: Connection refused

** (gnome-user-share:2643): WARNING **: gnome-user-share cannot be started as root for security reasons.

** (update-notifier:2689): WARNING **: not starting for system user

(gnome-settings-daemon:2418): color-plugin-WARNING **: Done switch to new account, reload devices

(gnome-settings-daemon:2418): color-plugin-WARNING **: Done switch to new account, reload devices

(gnome-settings-daemon:2418): color-plugin-WARNING **: Done switch to new account, reload devices

Comment: What do you mean "can't"? What are the symptoms? Any error messages?

Comment: I should have been more specific. Actually, the screen flashes black for a second, then takes me right back to the login screen where I have the option to login as the user or as a guest user. Additionally, each time I do that it has been creating zombie processes that I am having to go in and kill each time.

Comment: OK, please [edit] your question to include this information, it is easy to miss in the comments. Also include the contents of your `$HOME/.xsession-errors` file.

Comment: Yes. Alternatively, delete the file, then try to log in again. It will be recreated with only the latest errors.

Comment: Did you try deleting `~/.xsession-errors` and then attempting to log in again as I suggested before? That will remove the old errors and only show the ones that are relevant to your current issue.

Comment: Yes, what I did was I rm /home/timothy/.xsession-errors and it is gone. Then I hit f7 to get back into my GUI. I tried to log in as a user other than guest to try to catch the error. I then hit f1 to get back to my command line, and typed cat /home/timothy/.xsession-errors and it is now saying no such file exists....

Comment: I apologize for my ignorance, but I deleted the .xsession-errors file that was in my user folder, and now the only other one I can find is the much smaller one in the root folder. Is this the one I should post?

Comment: the issue is resolved. root had taken over my user account somehow.